# AutoMapper map ICollection<T> throws an Exception

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I'm trying to map one of my models into its DTO by using `AutoMapper`, my model:

```
public class Menu : BaseModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Route { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual Menu Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Menu> Children { get; set; }
}
```

And my DTO:

```
public class MenuDTO
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Route { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MenuDTO> Children { get; set; }
}
```

My mapping configuration profile:

```
CreateMap<Menu, MenuDTO>().ForMember(dest => dest.Children, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Children));
```

But it throws an `unsupported mapping exception` when executing:

```
Mapping types:
List`1 -> MenuDTO
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[App.Models.Menu, App, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> App.Models.MenuDTO
```

What's going wrong with that mapping config?

Comment: You have an infinite loop mate. Your menu class has a list of menus and each one of those has its own list of menus... you see where I'm going?

Comment: AM can handle recursive mappings.

Comment: @Marko Yes, I know it's a recursive model, but how to handle it in AM?

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu How exactly does it handle it? Automatically? How does it now when/where to stop with mapping?

Comment: I'm sure a little research will tell you how.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Oh right, brilliant, thanks for you helpful contribution to this discussion.

Comment: I'm guessing you want `ICollection<MenuDto> Children` in `MenuDto`? Also, the `MapFrom` is useless.

Comment: Yes, `ICollection<MenuDTO>` as its Children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your `Map` call looks like this:

`mapper.Map<MenuDTO>(new[]{new Menu()});`

instead of

`mapper.Map<List<MenuDTO>>(new[]{new Menu()});`

Comment: Mine is 
`var menu = _appUserRepository.GetMenu(); // IEnumerable<Menu>    
var menuDTO = _mapper.Map<MenuDTO>(menu);`

Comment: Anyway, look at the error message, it clearly states what's wrong. Your mapping works for me. The code you posted is not relevant for your error.

Comment: Ohh it works when the `Map` call be `_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MenuDTO>>(menu)` instead of `_mapper.Map<MenuDTO>(menu)`. I think the mistake is in the type of Map<T>, it should be a `Collection` of `MenuDTO`, not a single `MenuDTO`.

Comment: Clearly it has to match :)

Comment: Anw, my mapping profile is still be: `CreateMap<Menu, MenuDTO>().ForMember(dest => dest.Children, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Children));`. Is it okay?

Comment: You can remove it. It doesn't do anything in this case.

Comment: Yeah, finally I just need `CreateMap<Menu, MenuDTO>();` in my mapping profile. Thank you.